# Is lambda comparison deterministic?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

As we know, comparing two matching string literals can result in equality:

```
"hello" == "hello" //could be true or false
```

Does the same hold for lambdas:

```
[](){} == [](){} //false - guaranteed?
```

Is the compiler free to evaluate this as it pleases, or is it guaranteed that it will evaluate to `false`? Is it legal? What does the above actually compare?

Comment: Do closure types even *have* an `operator==`? I couldn't find a reference to that in a quick check...

Comment: LucDanton told me it wasn't guaranteed before.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cannot compare lambdas for equality. What you see in that little snippet is the lambdas being converted to function pointers and then the function pointers are compared. There are no guarantees that those function pointers are or are not the same, which means the result can be either `true` or `false`.

Comment: No, comparing function pointers is not undefined behaviour. The result is unspecified though.  (IOW, both `true` and `false` are valid results, but making you pregnant is not)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore The only thing that can happen is `true` or `false`.

Comment: Ah... so it **is** the same as string literals?

Comment: Is lambda one kind of callable object?

Comment: @Luchian well, yes, but for different reasons: string literals are explicitly allowed to overlap and then the arrays will decay to the same pointer. The lambdas don't need to overlap for them to convert to the same pointer.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes § 20.8.1 4 A callable object is an object of a callable type. Can I understand lambda as an object?

Comment: @billz anonymous functions.

Comment: @billz yes, lambdas are just regular function objects, with some special syntax on top and sometimes a few extras (like the aforementioned conversion to function pointers).

Comment: 5.1.2/6 says, "The value returned by this conversion function shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator". Since it doesn't say *which* such function is returned, this backs Martinho's claim. In principle if your no-capture lambda does nothing but pass its `const char*` parameter on to `strlen` then I think the conversion to function pointer could legally yield a pointer to `strlen` itself. Of course there's the usual uncertainty with the standard, there could be text elsewhere that adds more restrictions.